# Move all AcroFields from one pdf file to another (in same locations)

Tags: c#, itext

I have two documents that are structurally similar.  They all have tables, logos, headers, and footers which are all in the same locations.  However, one document has input fields for each entry in its tables and the other one does not.  Since their tables are structurally similar, the fields in the first PDF's tables would match the other.

How would I programmatically, using C# and ITextSharp, move all of the fields from one document to the other if they are structurally identical?

I have tried to copy the Acrofields from one document and simply put them in the other, but when I do this, I don't see any AcroFields show up in the resulting PDF.  This is my code:

```
public static void AddFormFieldsFromSource(string sourcePath, string secondSourcePath, string targetPath) {


  PdfReader readerMain = new PdfReader(sourcePath);
  readerMain.RemoveUsageRights();
  PdfReader readerSecond = new PdfReader(secondSourcePath);
  readerSecond.RemoveUsageRights();



  FileStream outStream = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

  PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(readerSecond, outStream);

  IDictionary<string, AcroFields.Item> fields = readerMain.AcroFields.Fields;


  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> field in fields) {
    stamp.AcroFields.Fields.Add(field);
  }

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");

  stamp.Close();

}
```

Comment: The structure might look the same but it actually doesn't exist. PDFs don't have headers, footers or tables, just text and lines pretty much. So ignoring those things, what you're looking to do is copy form fields, including their x,y positions and values from one PDF to another, right?

Comment: Seems you are looking for the `PdfCopyForms` class: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopyForms.html

Comment: That PdfCopyForms sounds like the class I need.  However, I am having trouble figuring out exactly how to use it.  Would anyone care to post an example demonstrating how to do it properly?

Comment: I think I figured out how to use it, but now I run into a StackOverflow error that occurs in the itextsharp dll.  More information here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893488/pdfcopyforms-in-itextsharp-causing-a-stack-overflow-error