# PdfCopyForms in ITextSharp causing a Stack Overflow error

Tags: c#, itext, stack-overflow

In this method I am trying to grab the input fields from one PDF document, paste them onto another document, and print out the result as a pdf file.  The result would be a new PDF file which has the input fields of the first PDF and the static content of the second PDF.

I wrote some code that I thought would perform this task, but I ran into a StackOverflow error each time "copier.close()" is executed.  This is the error that it throws:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

This is the code:

```
public static void AddFormFieldsFromSource(string sourcePath, string secondSourcePath, string targetPath) {
  lock (syncLock) {

    PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;

    PdfReader readerMain = new PdfReader(sourcePath);

    FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    PdfCopyForms copier = new PdfCopyForms(stream);

    PdfReader secondSourceReader = new PdfReader(secondSourcePath);

    copier.AddDocument(secondSourceReader);

    copier.CopyDocumentFields(readerMain);



    copier.Close();
    secondSourceReader.Close();
  }
}
```

The sourcepath is where I get my input fields from, and my second source path is where I get my static content from.

The PDF I used for the SourcePath variable is located here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qcc6ug8oohqvmca/primarytwopages2.pdf

The PDF I use for the secondSourcePath variable is located here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kx2rlhmizh46hl7/secondarytwopages.pdf

Also, on another note, I am using ITextSharp version 5.5.0.

Any idea why it is throwing the StackOverflow error?  I don't make any recursive calls in my code.  My first guess is that I am trying to do this task incorrectly.  The other possibility is that perhaps ITextSharp has a bug.

UPDATE: I downloaded the source code to the LATEST REVISION of ITextSharp (5.5.1), built a dll so I could debug, and then referenced that dll in my code.  The stack overflow error appears to occur in the class PdfIndirectReference in this method:

```
public class PdfIndirectReference : PdfObject {
....
        internal PdfIndirectReference(int type, int number, int generation) : base(0, new StringBuilder().Append(number).Append(' ').Append(generation).Append(" R").ToString()) {
        this.number = number;
        this.generation = generation;
    }
```

In the call stack of the dll code, I found that it recursively calls a method over and over again in

> itextsharp.text.pdf.PdfCopyFieldsImp.Propagate().

This must be why the stack overflow is occurring.

So, it doesn't occur in my code, but rather the dll.  Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Can you provide the pdf in question?

Comment: Sure.  Give me a few minutes and I'll provide a dropbox link.

Comment: K, now I put dropbox links in the question text.  They lead to the pdfs.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'll look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced the issue using iText and Java; the same issue occurs here, so quite likely the cause is the same.

`PdfCopyForms` internally uses `PdfCopyFormsImp` which is derived from `PdfCopyFieldsImp`. This latter class provides the base methods doing the heavy lifting of field and form copying, among them `propagate` which the OP has found multiple times in the call stack when the stack overflow occurs.

Contrary to the impression left by the observed stack overflow, `PdfCopyFieldsImp` *does* have a mechanism to prevent endless loops by marking objects already visited:

```
/**
 * Sets a reference to "visited" in the copy process.
 * @param   ref the reference that needs to be set to "visited"
 * @return  true if the reference was set to visited
 */
protected boolean setVisited(PRIndirectReference ref) {
    IntHashtable refs = visited.get(ref.getReader());
    if (refs != null)
        return refs.put(ref.getNumber(), 1) != 0;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This method at the same time marks an object reference from some `PdfReader` as visited and returns whether or not it has been visited before.

At least it does so for references from all `PdfReader` instances having an entry in the `visited` mapping, references from `PdfReader` instances without such an entry always are claimed to not have been visited yet (`return false`). Thus, references from those latter readers are not recognized as visited in case of multiple visits!

`PdfReader` instances get an entry in the `visited` mapping only in one code location: Only readers added to the copy using `addDocument` get it.

Using `PdfCopyForms` to add the form fields from one document to some other PDF, one obviously does *not* use `addDocument` for the reader with the form to copy but instead `copyDocumentFields`. Thus, loop prevention does not work here.

By adding an entry in the `visited` mapping for the reader from which the form is copied, one can prevent the Stack Overflow. I did it in `PdfCopyFormsImp.copyDocumentFields`

```
public void copyDocumentFields(PdfReader reader) throws DocumentException {
    if (!reader.isOpenedWithFullPermissions())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageLocalization.getComposedMessage("pdfreader.not.opened.with.owner.password"));
    if (readers2intrefs.containsKey(reader)) {
        reader = new PdfReader(reader);
    }
    else {
        if (reader.isTampered())
            throw new DocumentException(MessageLocalization.getComposedMessage("the.document.was.reused"));
        reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();
        reader.setTampered(true);
    }
    reader.shuffleSubsetNames();
    readers2intrefs.put(reader, new IntHashtable());

    visited.put(reader, new IntHashtable()); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    fields.add(reader.getAcroFields());
    updateCalculationOrder(reader);
}
```

In iTextSharp the analogous change would be in `PdfCopyFormsImp.CopyDocumentFields`:

```
    virtual public void CopyDocumentFields(PdfReader reader) {
        if (!reader.IsOpenedWithFullPermissions)
            throw new BadPasswordException(MessageLocalization.GetComposedMessage("pdfreader.not.opened.with.owner.password"));
        if (readers2intrefs.ContainsKey(reader)) {
            reader = new PdfReader(reader);
        }
        else {
            if (reader.Tampered)
                throw new DocumentException(MessageLocalization.GetComposedMessage("the.document.was.reused"));
            reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();
            reader.Tampered = true;
        }
        reader.ShuffleSubsetNames();
        readers2intrefs[reader] = new IntHashtable();

        visited[reader] =  new IntHashtable();  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        fields.Add(reader.AcroFields);
        UpdateCalculationOrder(reader);
    }
```

***Disclaimer:*** I have not checked whether `PdfCopyForms` works exactly as required after this change. I merely tested it in Java and only observed that no Stack Overflow occurs anymore and that the resulting PDF in the OP's use case looks ok.

Comment: You are awesome.  I will check this solution immediately when I get to work.  Then I will accept it as the answer (it probably is since Itext and itextsharp are identical)

Comment: The ITextSharp modification worked without a hitch!  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Michael! I had already made an internal ticket for this problem. I've updated the ticket with your answer. The fix will be in the next release.

Comment: Thank you. But beware, i made no in-depth analysis and, therefore, cannot say whether the proposed change has any unwanted side effects.